# Access to googlevideo.com was denied while using pytube

Tags: python, aws-lambda, youtube-data-api, http-status-code-403, pytube

On Local Machine video url works perfectly in browser.
@app.route('/get_video_url', methods = ['POST'])
def extract_video_url():
json_data = request.json
video_id = json_data['video_id']
video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}"
yt = YouTube(video_url)
video = yt.streams.get_lowest_resolution()
video = video.url
return jsonify({'video_url':video})

But when try to call from AWS Lambda it gives Access to rr2---sn-p5qs7nzy.googlevideo.com was denied.
@app.route('/video_url', methods = ['POST'])
def video_url():
json_data = request.json
video_id = json_data['video_id']
url = "https://rzjbxc42hpq6obcc2rpg56gvgy0nnrni.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/" #Lambda Function
response = requests.post(url,json={"video_id":video_id,"resolution":resolution})
data = response.json()
return data

python version 3.9.6
pytube version 15.0.0
pip version 23.1.2
Sever Zone N. Verginia, Lambda function zone N. Verginia

video_id:87JIOAX3njM
"video_url": "https://rr2---sn-p5qs7nzy.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1693962871&ei=F373ZJiMJIP68wSWsrLADw&ip=3.239.33.185&id=o-AMX0-shkqUZNqAco2Z1Qq9ADp68riEQstlQNgRqO35oK&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=4G&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-p5qs7nzy%2Csn-p5qlsny6&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=12&gcr=us&initcwndbps=1248750&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=11769364&ratebypass=yes&dur=152.064&lmt=1692463909375237&mt=1693940955&fvip=1&fexp=24007246&beids=24350018&c=ANDROID_MUSIC&txp=5530434&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cgcr%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgfCj-e6ebPZlDhBom_dty10Qho98VJk-GiE69VrX0zHACIBym6FmsRRyOrIe2fGhkwa-o1kf5tUOUkpek2mHh9ttl&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgQt9KstqFJixKLpnlOJ-PaTcQDFgLnYiDUyODhXuhzGoCIQDpqB3o3_lBweQcGOXwQTZwhK1gj5VaKvy8icM9WIGdhA%3D%3D"